# Window function to calculate On Balance Volume

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, window-functions

```
select a, b, Volume
case
    when lag(a, 1) over(order by b asc) < a then lag(c, 1) over(order by b asc) + Volume
    when lag(a, 1) over(order by b asc) > a then lag(c, 1) over(order by b asc) - Volume
end as c
from Table
```

So what I would like to achieve her is... if previous `a` row bigger/less then current `a` row then add/substract `Volume` from previous row `c`.

`if a > previous a c = previous c + Volume`
`if a < previous a c = previous c - Volume`

But... There is no `c` row because this is what I am calculating (so row `c`'s initial value is 0 or NULL) ... there is no pre defined set of data in `c`. One data coming from another... kind of.

If I would have to write this in another language I would store the value of `c` in a separate variable like `previousRow` and would rewrite it with each iteration.

Can I achieve similar thing in TSQL?

Sample Data:

| a | b | Volume | c |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2020-01 | 10 | 0 |
| 2 | 2020-02 | 20 | 20 |
| 5 | 2020-03 | 40 | 60 |
| 3 | 2020-04 | 30 | 30 |
| 1 | 2020-05 | 10 | 20 |

Comment: I put a sample table in the question. The code i am trying is what i already posted. This is where I am stuck.

Comment: It can be ordered by B (datetimeoffset)

Comment: @DaleK Here you go: https://www.investopedia.com/terms/o/onbalancevolume.asp

Find the formula in the article

Comment: Still not a valid date?

Comment: I highly suggest providing DDL+DML to create the sample data set so that its totally clear.

Answer (score 0):

column c pretty much boils down to a conditional rolling sum, unfortunately, sql server doesn't allow for nesting of window functions, so a derived table to establish the previous a value is necessary. After that, sum case when and  you should have what you're looking for.

Try this (added additional test values to the set provided above):

```
SELECT
  T.*,
  SUM(
      (
      CASE
      WHEN T.LAG_A IS NULL
        THEN 0
      WHEN T.A > T.LAG_A 
        THEN T.VOLUME 
        ELSE (T.VOLUME*-1) 
      END
    ) 
  ) OVER (ORDER BY T.B ASC) AS C
FROM
  (
  SELECT                 
    MY_TABLE.A,
    LAG(MY_TABLE.A, 1) OVER (ORDER BY MY_TABLE.B ASC) AS LAG_A,
    MY_TABLE.B,
    MY_TABLE.VOLUME
  FROM
    (VALUES (1,CAST('1/1/2021' AS DATE),10),
            (2,CAST('1/2/2021' AS DATE),20),
            (5,CAST('1/3/2021' AS DATE),40),
            (3,CAST('1/4/2021' AS DATE),30),
            (1,CAST('1/5/2021' AS DATE),10),
            (8,CAST('1/6/2021' AS DATE),50),
            (4,CAST('1/7/2021' AS DATE),70)
    ) AS MY_TABLE(A,B,VOLUME)
  ) T
```